# Eliminate Duplicate form entry linked to query result

Tags: mysql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I am new to VBA and Access and I have a query on a table which gives me only the active patients from my table as a result. The attached form allows my users to enter data into the table perfectly.

One of the fields for data entry on my form is the room number, which is not a unique field as far as the data in my table. However, on the query, this must be unique because there can not be two patients assigned to one room.

Is there a way to prevent users from assigning two active patients with the same room number using my query result? I have looked everywhere for an answer and the closest thing I have found was using DlookUp but I am unsure how this might work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest a 'Before_Update' event for the Room field on your form. There you could check to see if anyone else is in that room. Of course you could add a compound key to your table of Room and Active (or whatever) and have Access spit it out with an error... but that is not very user friendly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Wayne for your answer, I made the compound key but noticed the user would have to add lots of information into the form and hit enter only to see no patient added to the list. That didn't really get me what I was after but it sent me looking in the right direction...

I finally came up with a code to find the room numbers entered into the form by using Dcount on the query result and placed this code in the onExit event of the room number so I would be able to send the focus back to the field until the correct answer is submitted by the user.

I already had the field validation set to ensure the correct range of room numbers would be entered. This now has the potential of getting the user stuck in an endless loop. So, I will have to add another if statement to the error msg to send the user out of the loop if they just can't think of an empty room number to place into the field.

Anyway, here is the solution I came up with. 
First off, I added another text box "Me.txtResult" to my form to watch the results of Dcount which now isn't really necessary. However, it's in the code, so I thought I should explain that part.

```
Private Sub txtRoomNo_Exit(Cancel As Integer)
    On Error GoTo Err_txtRoomNo_Exit

    Dim strRmX As Integer
    Dim strRmNo As Integer

    strRmNo = Me.txtRoomNo

strRmX = DCount("[2017].[ID]", "2017 Query", "[2017].[Room#]=" & strRmNo)
    Me.txtResult = strRmX

    If strRmX > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Sorry, it appears the room number you entered" & vbCrLf & _
       "      is already occupied by another patient" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
       "      Click OK to try another room number.", vbCritical, 
       "Surgical Weaning Tool          User Data Entry Error!"

       Me.txtRoomNo.SetFocus
    End If


    Exit_txtRoomNo_Exit:
    Exit Sub
    Err_txtRoomNo_Exit:
       MsgBox "        Error: For Room# Entry Duplicate Check" & vbCrLf & _
   "                      for New Patient Form" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
   "     " & Error$ & " " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
   "  Please write down ALL the above message and" & vbCrLf & _
   "                      Inform Jim about this error" & vbCrLf & _
   "                  As Soon As Possible. Thank You!" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
   "      Please double check the room number you" & vbCrLf & _
   "                  just entered is not alread in use!", vbCritical, 
   "Surgical Weaning Tool   -   -    ERROR!"
        Resume Exit_txtRoomNo_Exit

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry that you went to the trouble of trying the compound-key - I mentioned that as a joke of what not to do :(  Another option you could consider would be to use a comboBox to allow the user to select a room number, and have the source be a query that lists all 'open' rooms.